# Codeingiter Query For Order by in my particular column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want order by query. My issue for the website is below.

I have a news table in my database and the table having order and date columns.

Now i want to display a news by  today date with order of news.

For example : XXXx news having order 1 and yyyy news having order 1 and zzzz news having order 1 and aaa news order is 2.

I have displayed this value in ascending..so the result is

```
xxxx
yyyy
zzzz
aaaa
```

When i addded another news ie bbbb and order 1 then it's comes under zzzz

ie

```
xxxx
yyyy
zzzz
bbbb
aaaa
```

But i want the result is

```
bbbb
xxxx
yyyy
zzzz
aaaa
```

Note : The date is same date ie. today date

how do i get this? let me know

Comment: use `order by date desc`

Comment: If You do have only `DATE` column without `time`, then we can't help You

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ORDER BY` with multiply columns. That's what you have:

```
(value) (order)
xxxx    order=1
yyyy    order=1
zzzz    order=1
bbbb    order=1
aaaa    order=2
```

And to get this:

```
(value) (order)
bbbb    order=1
xxxx    order=1
yyyy    order=1
zzzz    order=1
aaaa    order=2
```

Just `ORDER BY` `order` and then by `value`.

`ORDER BY order, value`

Answer (score 0):

```
if your requirement is to show result from current date and order by order in ci then use this:

$this->db->where("date",date('Y-m-s'));//whatever date format you have store in table place here
$this->db->order_by("order","ASC");  //$this->db->order_by("order","DESC");// according to requirement

Or if your requirement is to show result date wise on order wise both order and date then:

$this->db->order_by("date","ASC");
$this->db->order_by("order","ASC");
$this->db->order_by("id","DESC");
```